# What is ruling related to 'Forefinger rule' of prayers?

Tags: salat, tashahhud

There are many hadiths ruling on the 'forefinger rule' but I have no problem with them. I have studied the book, 'Guide to prayer from beginning to end'. There I read hadiths and also from other sources, I got knowledge about the 'forefinger rule' but I didn't get any of them ruling on raising down the finger along with raising it up.

So my question is: Should we lower our index finger after testifying with it or is it to be still raised until end of prayer? And also tell me when exactly to raise it and, if it *is* to be moved down, when it is to be done exactly?

Comment: This is a matter in which there is a clear difference of opinion; please edit your question to indicate if you're asking about the ruling according to any particular school of jurisprudence (if so, which school?), or are you looking for a general summary (rather than an actual *ruling*) of the dispute itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mufti Obaid Ullah (*Mufti of Darul Uloom Karachi, Hanafi School of Thought*), when the person is in the act of *Tashahhud* (تشھد ), and he is reading *AtTahiyyat*(التحیات), he should raise his finger on the start of it i.e on **`"Ashhadu Allah.... (الشھد الله)"`**
and he should bring it down on **`"IlLallah.... (الا الله)"`** 
This practice belongs to *Hanafi* School of thought. However, in Maliki school, they continue to raise their finger up and down till Salam i.e the end of prayer. 
***And ALLAH knows the best***

Comment: What do you think is the righteous way to have such action?

Comment: raise it up at the start, raise down on IlLallah

Comment: Do you have hard reasons to do it?

Comment: Because Sunni's use to follow the Imam. And the Fiqah of Imam Abu Hanifa tells us to do so.

Comment: It is not the reason anymore! Are you following Islam just because of your ancestors and Imam are doing so i.e. whatsoever they do, you do. This is actually baseless concept for you of Islam. You should seek one yourself and not just rely on your elder's rulings. The God shall ask us individually so we should prepare ourselves for it individually. I don't intend to prove you or your community wrong nor your concepts but all I want to tell is that explore out the Islam yourself and if you find no wrong with your concepts then let it go. May God befall guidance upon you.